# What is a good Jquery scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

What is a good Jquery scrollbar?

Comment: What's wrong with jScrollPane?

Comment: Im sorry, jScrollPane is awesome...

Comment: There is none. They have all difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/)?

Updated, thanks Giorgio

Comment: Broken link, you mean http://jquerytools.org don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few plugins:

[Custom scrollbar](http://web-resources.net/tools/fully-customizable-content-scrollbar-jquery-plugin.html)

[slimScroll](http://web-resources.net/development-scrollbar/slimscroll-jquery-plugin.html)